# IBM Workload Scheduler: Performance issue when running EDWA with mirroring enabled

Tags: scheduler, mirroring, workload-scheduler

Event-driven workload automation (EDWA) rules seem to have reduced performance when mirroring is enabled:

after submitting a relevant number of jobs with EDWA and waiting for a few hours, the status of the jobs when viewed from a DWC with mirroring enabled is not correctly updated.

Can you offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To improve EDWA performance I suggest you increase the number of DB connections from 0 (minimum) to 60 (maximum) and set the number of threads to 25 in the DefaultWorkManager configuration panel, from the WAS console.